# Make image sprite inside canvas follow mouse

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I have been struggling with this all day. I can make the image follow the mouse pointer but when i try to turn the image angle i cannot make it work. You can check the code here: [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/vejejap/edit?js,console,output).
There is a another black square following the mouse in the correct way but i cannot make it work with the sprite image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correctly translating for the rotation to occur in the center of the image. You need to translate by half the width and height, do the rotation, then translate back.

I've updated your SpriteImage render method to correctly translate:

```
this.render = function(xPos, yPos, scale, w, h, angle) {
  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(xPos, yPos);
  ctx.translate(w/2, h/2);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.translate(-w/2, -h/2);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

  //console.log('angle:',angle);
  ctx.drawImage(this.img, 
      this.x, this.y, 
      w, h, 
      0, 0, 
      width*scale, height*scale);
  ctx.restore();
};
```

[Edit]
Here's a link to the jsbin with the updated code: http://output.jsbin.com/tulimaxavu/1/edit

Comment: It's worth taking the time at this point to play around with how affine transforms work in general, and how they relate to the canvas in js. In the case, you can think of each transform as "stacking" on the previous one, and they all occur with respect to the current origin. If you want the center of the image to be where the rotation occurs, you need to translate to it, then rotate. Then you need to translate back to the upper left corner so that when you draw it, it's in the right spot. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it did help me to understand I was missing to translate the origin of rotation back to where it started. Thanks again Yona.